# How to display all results without ending with the first match?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I display all results without ending with the first match? This code helps me get text between start&end words. But the search ends after the first pair found. How do you find all the matches?

```
const file = fs.readFileSync('./history.txt', 'utf8')
const startString = '-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------'
const endString = '-----EndCompilerOutput---------------'
const startIndex = file.indexOf(startString) + startString.length
const endIndex = file.indexOf(endString)
const between = file.slice(startIndex, endIndex)
console.log(between)
```

Comment: Completely unclear what you are trying to do here. You are not "finding" anything here.

Comment: What is the desired output?  Please show an example if the input and the desired output so we can better tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to find text between given labels. Since there are more than two such word pairs, I do not want the search to end with the first match.
Why are you saying that I'm not looking for anything here? This code searches for matches and displays the result. This is also a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i understood  correctly

```
const file = fs.readFileSync('./history.txt', 'utf8');

const startString = '-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------';
const endString = '-----EndCompilerOutput---------------';
var startIndex = file.indexOf(startString);

while(startIndex > -1) {
    // get index after '-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------'
    let start = startIndex + startString.length;

// -----------------------------------
// EDIT: WRONG --> let end = file.indexOf(endString);
// Need to start searching for next occurence starting at index after the start
// -----------------------------------

    // get index before '-----EndCompilerOutput---------------'
    let end = file.indexOf(endString, start);

    // get the text between
    console.log(file.slice(start, end));

    // set startIndex to next index of '-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------'
    // if not found the startIndex value will be -1 so end of the while loop
    startIndex = file.indexOf(startString, end + endString.length);
}
```

EDIT:

Example file:

```
-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
test1
-----EndCompilerOutput---------------
-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
test2
-----EndCompilerOutput---------------
```

Output:

```
test1


test2
```

Comment: For some reason, the code does not produce any visible result (

Comment: I fixed the bug in my code. See edits. I tested it and it works as expected. It produces some empty lines but i leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks. This is what I just wanted to do.